# Can I use With within another with?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I am trying to create something like this but end up in errors. Not sure if this is the right way to do.

```
WITH SECONDMAIN AS
(
     WITH MAIN AS
     (
         SELECT
         ....
     )
     SELECT
        *
     FROM MAIN M
     JOIN ....
)

SELECT * FROM SECONDMAIN SM;
```

Comment: Hi B001, I'm using Oracle DBMS, I'm trying to have a with within another with. but it doesn't seem to work. not sure if that's the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax would be-

```
 WITH MAIN AS
 (
     SELECT
     ....
 ), 
 SECONDMAIN AS
 (
     SELECT
        *
     FROM MAIN M
     JOIN ....
)

SELECT * FROM SECONDMAIN SM;
```